# Создание компонента

Tags: меню, кроссплатформенность, прокрутка, компоненты, qt

Мне необходимо с использованием `Qt` создать свой компонент, который будет предназначаться для создания меню. Из себя он представляет поверхность со `Scroll` по вертикали, на которой будут располагаться кнопки, причем их количество можно менять.
Вопрос: что сначала стоит почитать перед созданием компонента и на какой поверхности лучше создавать эти кнопки, чтоб самому не писать код для вертикальной прокрутки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты плохо знаком с Qt, то читай учебник, например, макс шлее http://qt4.ru/blog/books/4.html .

Если дела получше, то читай документацию по QScrollArea. В неё помещаешь слой (один из QLayout) и добавляешь в слой необходимое количество кнопок (любых виджетов). С помощью SizePolicy установишь необходимое поведение размера.